# SQL Server Query Performance Degradation and Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I've inherited several data sources and I've been tasked with integration and report.  Nothing new.

The issue is that while I have a working integrated query (as a view), performance degrades daily (from 8 to 12 seconds).

Here is a slightly simplified version of the table schema and a working query to get the list of tickets.

```
/*  Table Schema  */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KioskImport](
    [ImportID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ImportDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [TICKET_NBR] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [TTL_AMT] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [GROUP_ID] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [SALE_DT] [date] NULL,
    [SALE_TMS] [time](0) NULL,
    [BADGE_NO] [varchar](25) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

/*  Working Query  */
SELECT 
    [KioskImport].TICKET_NBR
    ,[KioskImport].GROUP_ID
    ,[KioskImport].TTL_AMT
    ,CONVERT(datetime, [KioskImport].SALE_DT) + CONVERT(datetime, [KioskImport].SALE_TMS) AS [SALE_DATE]
    ,[KioskImport].BADGE_NO
FROM [KioskImport]
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(ImportID) MaxID, MAX(ImportDate) MaxDate, TICKET_NBR
    FROM [KioskImport]
    GROUP BY TICKET_NBR
) [MaxRevenueImport]
ON [MaxRevenueImport].MaxID = [KioskImport].ImportID
AND [MaxRevenueImport].MaxDate = [KioskImport].ImportDate
```

From here I have a view that joins several queries like this to create a product result set.

Does anyone have good suggestions on how to optimize this query so as to mitigate the ongoing performance degradation (buying enough time to redesign...everything).

SQL Version is 2008 R2

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: There is also a strange issue here... you are taking the max date and max id and joining both of those back, but they are independent -- are you sure the same record holds the max date as the max id -- and if you are then maxid should be all you need to join on since in is unique.

Comment: Do you have any indexes?

Comment: Amended the SQL version.

Comment: Date and ID are in the same record.  Both are used in the query because both are defined in the clustered index.  Using a single field in the query is demonstrably slower than using both fields.

Comment: Without the execution plan, we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the other folks pointed out, you should note what version of SQL you are using.  That said, this might perform better as a `CROSS APPLY`.  Try changing your query to:

```
SELECT 
    [KioskImport].TICKET_NBR
    ,[KioskImport].GROUP_ID
    ,[KioskImport].TTL_AMT
    ,CONVERT(datetime, [KioskImport].SALE_DT) + CONVERT(datetime, [KioskImport].SALE_TMS) AS [SALE_DATE]
    ,[KioskImport].BADGE_NO
FROM [KioskImport] kiOuter
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        kiInner.TICKET_NBR
    FROM [KioskImport] kiInner
    GROUP BY
        kiInner.TICKET_NBR
    HAVING 
        MAX(kiInner.ImportID) = kiOuter.ImportID
        AND MAX(kiInner.ImportDate) = kiOuter.ImportDate
    ) kiInner
```

Also, if you're seeing query performance change this dramatically over the course of a single day, you likely either are having fragmentation from heavy table churn, are comparing cached vs. uncached query performance, or the server is running other workloads.

Comment: Double checked the performance and I overstated, it is up to 12 seconds per week, not per day.  Indices appear contiguous and in good condition.  This is a shared server so other workloads are likely.

Answer (score 0):

I bet 'cross apply' run slower. My question for you is when you have MAX(kiInner.ImportID) what is MAX(kiInner.ImportDate) for that ImportID, or when you get MAX(kiInner.ImportDate) what is MAX(kiInner.ImportID) for that ImportDate. They maybe not in the same row. I suggest to use CTE.

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT TICKET_NBR
               , ImportID
               , ImportDate
               , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TICKET_NBR              
                    ORDER BY ImportDate DESC, ImportID DESC) AS Rownum
          FROM KioskImport
)
SELECT [KioskImport].TICKET_NBR
    ,[KioskImport].GROUP_ID
    ,[KioskImport].TTL_AMT
    ,CONVERT(datetime, [KioskImport].SALE_DT) + CONVERT(datetime,  [KioskImport].SALE_TMS) AS [SALE_DATE]
    ,[KioskImport].BADGE_NO
FROM [KioskImport] k
INNER JOIN cte cte
     ON cte.ImportID = k.ImportID
     AND cte.ImportDate = k.ImportDate
     AND cte.Rownum = 1;
```

Comment: The CROSS APPLY works but does not demonstrate any difference either positively or negatively.

Answer (score 0):

use this before the select :

```
SELECT MAX(ImportID) MaxID, MAX(ImportDate) MaxDate, TICKET_NBR
into #MaxRevenueImport
    FROM [KioskImport]
    GROUP BY TICKET_NBR
```

then use #MaxRevenueImport at your join. If #MaxRevenueImport has more than 10000 rows create index on the temp at TICKET_NBR before the join in the main select.
Do not use table variable use temp #.